# Need help extracting Windows 7 Enterprise aero.theme file

Tags: windows-7, zip, extract, aero

Ok SuperUsers, I need help extracting the native aero.theme file. (Not the downloaded themepacks). This is the one that ships natively with Windows 7 Enterprise. Specifically I am looking to get the pre-logon Windows 7 Enterprise background picture in jpg, eps, tif or any other picture format. Please feel free to ask any clarifying questions you need but the goal is to get the picture in electronic format of the background that you see when you're at the login prompt for Win 7 Enterprise. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Windows\System32\oobe\background.bmp

Comment: the logon background image also has various sizes stored in C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll (if you are running x86). You can extract them using a tool like PE Explorer.